# Find the hyperbolic length of the geodesic segment

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm reading my textbook and I'm trying to make sense of this example.

[image]

So the place with the red star shows the actual process of calculating the hyperbolic length. My question is how they get the number 8, -1 and 4.

I've been trying to calculate with different numbers but I keep getting square roots, and I've calculated two times but I still can't get those numbers. I've tried it with the same method they calculated CB and CA but it doesn't give me 8, -1 or 4.

If anyone can tell me how to get those numbers, that would help a lot.

Comment: Those are coordinates of the points $A, B, C$.

Comment: @Travis what do you mean? aren't the numbers the length? like for example $\frac{7}{4}$

Comment: What is your formula for hyperbolic length?

Comment: $\ln\frac{\csc \beta -\cot \beta}{\csc \alpha -\cot \alpha}$

Comment: And what are $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are angles. I just gave the general form

Comment: such as in this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs1wE.png

Comment: @Travis, never mind. I got it, they were the coordinates.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. :)

Comment: "I'm reading my textbook" which book and on which page ? (there are so many books)

Comment: @Willemien Oh, I'll make sure to specify in future posts. It Saul Stahl's The Poincare Half-Plane